# Why nested SQL inside OLE DB Source not work?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I'm developing a SSIS package to perform extractions from SQL Server 2008 to an Excel file.

This is my data flow:
[image]

"Extraction of concepts" is an OLE DB Source. It executes this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    Surname,
    (
        SELECT 
            CI.Interest + '; '
        FROM                
            CustomerInterests CI
        WHERE 
            CI.CustomerId = C.ID
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) AS Interest 
FROM
    Customer C
WHERE Id = ?
```

When I try to save my query I get this error:
[image]

If I modify my SQL Statement like following, the error does not appear:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    Surname,
    NULL AS Interest 
FROM
    Customer C
WHERE Id = ?
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, follow the below steps:
1) Add variable in SSIS called ID
2) In your WHERE Statement 
Use : **WHERE @Id = ?**
3) Assign the @ID varible in Data flow with ID SSIS varibale.

**Updated:**
[image]

Comment: Hi Maverick, first of all thanks for your answer. Can I have more information about third point?

Comment: @ilMattion - I have updated my answer. Follow the steps you will achieve what you need.